# Getting "MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017" in Docker Compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am doing a REST API with Express and MongoDB. Everything works perfectly locally. I want to dockerize the database and the backend using Docker Compose.

The Mongo Docker works perfectly, but the backend fails to connect to it. It keeps throwing me this error:

```
/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797

  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();

                               ^


MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)

    at /backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10

    at /backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5

    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

    at promiseOrCallback (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)

    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1167:10)

    at Mongoose.connect (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:340:20)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/backend/index.js:11:3)

    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10) {

  reason: TopologyDescription {

    type: 'Unknown',

    servers: Map(1) {

      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {

        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },

        address: 'localhost:27017',

        type: 'Unknown',

        hosts: [],

        passives: [],

        arbiters: [],

        tags: {},

        minWireVersion: 0,

        maxWireVersion: 0,

        roundTripTime: -1,

        lastUpdateTime: 14312460,

        lastWriteDate: 0,

        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

            at connectionFailureError (/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:293:20)

            at Socket.<anonymous> (/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:267:22)

            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)

            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)

            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)

            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)

            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

      }

    },

    stale: false,

    compatible: true,

    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,

    localThresholdMS: 15,

    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined

  }

}
```

I've read online that the issue could be that I shouldn't connect to localhost but to the MongoDB container.

I attach the files:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    data:
      container_name: data
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      volumes:
        - ./data/db:/data/db
    
    backend:
      container_name: backend
      depends_on:
        - data
      build: ./backend
      ports:
        - 5000:5000
      environment:
        - DB_HOST=data
        - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME?:}
        - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT?:}
```

/backend/Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
WORKDIR /backend

EXPOSE 5000

ENV PORT=5000
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

# install backend dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only-production

# add backend
COPY . .

# start backend
CMD npm start
```

/backend/index.js

```js
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const property = require("./routes/property-router")
const properties = require("./routes/properties-router")
const statistics = require("./routes/statistics-router")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const dbConfig = require("./config/db.config")
require("dotenv").config();
var cors = require("cors")


// Connect to MongoDB database
mongoose
    .connect(dbConfig.url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
        const app = express()

        app.use(cors())

        app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: '*/*'}))

        app.use("/api", statistics)
        app.use("/api", properties)
        app.use("/api", property)

        const PORT = dbConfig.port || 5000;

        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
        });
    })
```

/backend/config/db.config.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const {
    DB_HOST,
    DB_PORT,
    DB_NAME,
    PORT,
  } = process.env;
  
  module.exports = {
    url: `mongodb://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`,
    port: PORT
  };
```

/backend/.env

```
PORT=5000
HOST=localhost

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_NAME=propertyDB
DB_PORT=27017
```

Running the backend locally I can connect to the MongoDB Docker without any issues.  By leaving only the data in the Docker Compose file and running node index.js.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

I have even changed the URL from index.js to a random URL and still remains the same error and tries to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017.

```
.connect("randomurl.com", { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Comment: I've restored a deleted file in this post, since it appears in an answer below. If you have now removed that file, put it in an update section. On Stack Overflow, questions and answers are kept for posterity, and they must be understandable to readers who did not read it when it was new.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers behave like nodes in a network. Unless you tell it not to, Docker Compose creates a virtual network, and assigns DNS names inside that network corresponding to the service names in the `docker-compose.yml` file. The values in `.env` overwrite the environment variables in `docker-compose.yml`.

You can remove (i.e. not copy) the `.env` file and set the values using environment variables by adding `.env` to `.dockerignore`.

Alternatively, you can change

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

to

```
DB_HOST=data
```

in `.env`. The `.env` file should contain

```
PORT=5000
HOST=localhost

DB_HOST=data
DB_NAME=propertyDB
DB_PORT=27017
```

Comment: I've already tried, it does not work. But I get your point. Still tells me that is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 and the exact same error.

Comment: He's overwriting it on the docker-compose with `environment: - DB_HOST=data`

Comment: @DavidVives: your `.env` file is overwriting the env vars for the backend service. You can take out any variables here that are provided by the Docker Compose file.

Comment: @DavidVives Can you post your project with `DB_HOST=data`? Where did you change it? I mean you have to set it in `.env`

Comment: the env file is not impacting the db_host name since its not referenced in the compose file and also not used with the `env_file` key.

Comment: but its copied into the image on build. This might be an issue.

Comment: @TheFool `require('dotenv').config();` reads the `.env` file and overwrites the values of `process.env`

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant with my last comment, *its copied on build*.

Comment: Probably best not to copy the file on build.

Comment: @TheFool That's the alternative in my answer.

Comment: @TheFool Ok so i've tried all you guys have said but haven't found a solution, I literally deleted all the "localhosts" from the project but the error keeps being the same. Also I've deleted the .env files, won't work either. The error remains the same, i don't know what i'm missing. Thanks guys

Comment: @jabaa also for you

Comment: @DavidVives: without a meaningful update (i.e. a detailed explanation of your new work) there is nothing for people to go on, and they will just have to do a fresh loop of asking you what code you have in front of you. Perhaps you could try rebuilding your images, bringing your containers down, and then bringing them up again.

Comment: did you rebuild the image? I would advise to list the .env file in .dockerignore and then making sure that the image is rebuild.

Comment: @DavidVives I've copied all the code from your question, removed the routes (because you didn't provide the files), and replaced your `.env` with mine. The server works and is connected to the database.

Comment: @jabaa what did you put on your .env ?

Comment: @DavidVives You can use the `.env` file from my answer.

Comment: Using the env file is not a good idea,  it takes away the selling point of env vars. Now you have to rebuild the image each time, some configuration changes or at least mount the adjusted env file. That seems like an antipattern.

Comment: @TheFool Brooo! We found the issue. We weren't deleting the image from docker. So we spend 5hours running the same fckng image hahaah. Thanks mate, you were right.

Comment: @DavidVives `docker-compose up --build` would have done the trick.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that when you run the docker compose a new image is created and stored. So every time you run the same container the same image will be executed.
What you have to do is the following:

For the first step, you should first shut down any running docker-compose configurations:

```
$ docker-compose down
```

You can use the following command to verify that nothing is left running:

```
$ docker ps --all
```

To remove locally build images, first list all of the images cached locally, then remove anything that was built locally:

```
$ docker images
```

Then remove the image that is giving you issues.

```
$ docker rmi <image_name>
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: There's a couple of ways of solving this. As The Fool says, a rebuild would do the trick. Also, in a dev environment, an on-host volume that gives a live view of the code is helpful (this reduces the number of rebuilds required in a dev env).

Comment: That's not true, we executed --force-rebuild and it did not remove the image